# My bootstrap css file is damage

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

hi I am using bootstrap about a month, I never get that kind of error, I just want to change my menu into transparent so I get help from stack overflow and then I changed my menu. but when I changed my menu my slider pictures are out of slider showing and my list box text is mismanaged. I don't know what's wrong. I just edit my `CSS` code .

```
.navbar {
    background-color: transparent;    
    background: transparent; 
}
.navbar li { 
    color: #000 
}
```

**slider code:**

> ```
> <!-- Insert to your webpage where you want to display the slider -->
> <div id="amazingslider-1" style="display:block;position:relative;margin:16px auto 32px;">
>     <ul class="amazingslider-slides" style="display:none;">
>         <li><img src="images/header1.jpg" alt="header1" /></li>
>         <li><img src="images/header2.jpg" alt="header2" /></li>
>         <li><img src="images/header3.jpg" alt="header3" /></li>
>         <li><img src="images/header4.jpg" alt="header4" /></li>
>         <li><img src="images/header5.jpg" alt="header5" /></li>
>     </ul>
>     <div class="amazingslider-engine" style="display:none;"><a href="http://amazingslider.com">JavaScript Slideshow</a></div>
> </div>
> <!-- End of body section HTML codes -->
> ```

**menu code:**

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top"
 role="navigation">
       <div class="container">
         <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
             <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           </button>
           <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bootstrap theme</a>
         </div>
         <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
           <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
             <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
             <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
             <li class="dropdown">
               <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                 <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                 <li class="divider"></li>
                 <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                 <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
               </ul>
             </li>
           </ul>
         </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
       </div>
     </div>
```

can anyone help?

Comment: You should try to replicate issue on jsFiddle

Comment: `my slider pictures are out of slider showing` If I understand this correctly (not sure), it seems as if the hidden images are supposed to be 'hiding' behind a background. Since you've now made the background transparent, you can see through it and see the otherwise hidden images. It's like trying to hide behind a glass wall. Everyone can still see you. :) If this is not the case, please post more relevant code so we understand the problem better.

Comment: this is not the case, my slider images are working before when i changed the code but now the images which i placed in the slider are showing vertical. if i change the code that i changed before then the slider and the other things are working properly which i don't want.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your code is ok.There are some suggestions.
Try using specific child selector. Use a parent class to your navbar div.

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top"
 role="navigation">
       <div class="container">
         <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
             <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           </button>
           <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bootstrap theme</a>
         </div>
         <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
           <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
             <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
             <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
             <li class="dropdown">
               <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                 <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                 <li class="divider"></li>
                 <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                 <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
               </ul>
             </li>
           </ul>
         </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
       </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

And for css

```
.parent .navbar {
    background-color: transparent;    
    background: transparent; 
}
.parent .navbar li { 
    color: #000 
}
```

Hope that it will avoid conflict with other rules.